# Fill in values from within same data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with missing values and need to fill them in based on other rows in the same data.table. I can do this by duplicating the data.table and filtering by the unique values in the row I'm trying to fill in, but I'm thinking there must be a more elegant way to do this without using so much memory. I also don't know if it's possible to reference the same data.table within itself because of the confusion of column names.

In this example, there is a doc number, value, and entry type. If possible, I need the solution to include both the doc number and entry type as the keys for filling in the value. Entry type 11 never has a value - the value can be stored with an entry type 16 or a type NA.

```
test <- data.table(docnumber = c(100023,100024,100024,100024,
                                 100025,100025,100026,100026), 
                   value = c(15423,15428,NA,NA,
                             17832,NA,23162,NA), 
                   type = c(16,16,11,12,NA,11,16,11)
)
test
```

Here's what the result should look like:

```
results <- data.table(docnumber = c(100023,100024,100024,100024,100025,100025,100026,100026), value = c(15423,15428,15428,15428,17832,17832,23162,23162), type = c(16,16,11,12,NA,11,16,11))
results
```

Comment: Based on the example, I assume you could do `test[, value := unique(na.omit(value)), by = docnumber]` but I'm not sure what the relevance of the `type` column is..

Comment: And if it has this sort order, `test[, value := value[1L], by=docnumber]`. If `value` is fully determined by `docnumber`, while `type` is not, you should probably be thinking about using a better data structure. Here's the usual reference in the R community: http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. Type would just be another key to identify the right unique values - I can supply that to the by argument and that should work if I have multiple values within a docnumber.